# Running Wildfly 10.1.0 with limited user permissions

Tags: linux, wildfly

I have a wildfly 10 install running on CentOS Linux 7.3.1611 with kernel3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64.

Initially when I started running wildfly I was doing so as root in a domain configuration.  I have decided to change this practice and configure it as a service.  After configuring it as a service, and letting it run for a while I decided to create a user "wildfly", and make the appropriate changes to the systemd service config and directory permissions.  Wildfly starts up properly and the application runs fine.

My issue starts when I try and create another server instance from the management console.  The console records the server but its never able to start.  After some checking I found wildfly is unable to create server directories.  This occurs even when having permissions to do so.

The only error I get is this one from /var/log/audit/audit.log;

type=ANOM_ABEND msg=audit(1507241312.223:19650): auid=4294967295 uid=994 gid=994 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0 pid=8570 comm="java" reason="memory violation" sig=6

I have disabled SELinux, and checked the ACL's on all files in the directory structure.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe just lauch it manually with the user you've created to get more infos